# How to prevent VF Remoting from failing when there's no Referer header in the request?

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, httprequest

I'm working on a ReactJS app served through a VisualForce page.

If the initial request *to* the page containing the app doesn't include an HTTP Referer header, none of the requests sent to the page's controller via JavaScript Remoting include a Referer header either.

This causes the remoting requests to fail with the message "Unable to determine from which page the request originated".

Is there anyway to get VF Remoting to not fail because an optional header isn't coming through?

Or, alternately, is there some way to force the VF page server to include a Referer header?

Comment: Can you post some code you have written so far ?